# Facebook api shows only statuses of the last year

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm working with a facebook app that  aims to show all user statuses, after a couple of questions here on stackoverflow ,  i got this (almost )working.
The problem is that graph api show only statuses of last year.
Is not a script problem because if i use the Graph Api explorer tool , the json output is the same (now - october 2013).
tested with several facebook account, same problem.
Any idea / help? thanks

**UPDATE:**
Basically i get data from : `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?fields=statuses` (this is from Explorer api tool), script code is

```
" $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/statuses' ); "
```

In both ways i got same result. (using explorer tool or by script). few statuses and i cant go back untill very old statuses.
But the problem is not my code , i'm asking because maybe there are some limitation , not listed in docs. As Wizkid suggest i've filed a bug.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Show some code, or nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a Bug.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298184123723116/
```

> We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid
>   bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.